# Finding a generator for the product of two ideals in $ \mathbb{C}[X][Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $f, g\in\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ be two irreducible elements in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ such that $(f) \neq (g)$.
> Give a generator for the ideal $((f) + (g)) \cdot ((f) \cap (g))$.

I figured out that $(f) \cap (g) = (fg)$, because $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is a UFD and so $(f) \cap (g) = (\operatorname{lcm}(f, g))$, but I haven’t been able to figure out the rest.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a unique generator or for more than one ? This ideal doesn't seem to be principal and I might be wrong but I think you can write your ideal as $(f^2g, fg^2)$.

Comment: I suppose knowing the unique generator for the ideal would be better. Can I ask you how you came to the conclusion that $(f^2g,fg^2)$ is a (or the) generator for the ideal?

Comment: Since $\mathbb C[X, Y]$ is not principal you cannot be sure that such an element exists. Did you come up with this or was it in a reference ? For the rest, I wrote $((f)+(g)) \cdot ((f)\cap (g)) = (f, g) \cdot (fg) = (f^2g, fg^2)$ but I would advise you to be careful with my computations.

Comment: No I didn't come up with it, it was in a reference. You used that $(f)+(g)=(f,g)$, but is that true in general?

Comment: yes, it's just a different notation